# -bash ng command not found Mojave

Tags: node.js, angular, macos, npm, macos-mojave

Ive had this issue for a few days now. Ive been searching in many posts about this same problem but none of them gives me a solution. I hope you can help me.

I installed node.js a few days ago, then installed angular with the usual comands:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

After it was done, i was able to use ng help, or ng new. Everything was fine but then i accidentally uninstalled angular. After i tried to install it again an use ng commands, the error was displayed:

> -bash: ng command not found**

I tried a lot of solutions that were posted, tried to change the alias:

```
alias ng="Users/jg/.npm-global/bin/ng"
```

And after that command it gave me another eror:

> -bash: Users/jg/.npm-global/bin/ng: No such file or directory**

I dont know what is happening but I hope you guys can save me. If not i would need to format mi computer lol.

*I have macOS Mojave 10.14.2*

Comment: Try restarting the terminal after installing @angular/cli

Comment: @Prasheel just need to close it and then open it again?

Comment: Yes. Just close it and open it again

Comment: @Prasheel and after i open it i need to try ng again? what do i use? ng -v, ng help or?

Comment: Install angular cli using npm i -g @angular/cli, once it is installed, close the terminal, open the terminal again, run ng -v. This should work

Comment: @Prasheel mm i tried closing the terminal after installing angular, then open it and typed ng -v, displayed same error

Comment: Can you paste the output of npm i -g @angular/cli ??

Comment: @Prasheel                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          npm i -g @angular/cli
/Users/mac/.npm-global2/bin/ng -> /Users/mac/.npm-global2/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
+ @angular/cli@7.2.3
updated 1 package in 15.665s

Comment: Why is is .npm-global2 ?

Comment: @Prasheel i remember changing the path in some of the solutions i read but i had the error before i did the change.

Comment: Just make sure you have it installed  in .npm-global and not . npm-global2

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for Mac users  " bash: ng command not found "

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5021#issuecomment-377030706

I followed the steps and ng command issue has been fixed.

Comment: Not solving, same issue